# ng-blur does not submit form when pressing enter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form for my search criteria:

```
 <form ng-submit="ctrl.search()">
     <number-textbox data-format-number="false" data-vertical="true" data-edit-mode="true" data-value="searchNumber"></number-textbox>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
         <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
         {{ 'customers.Search' | translate }}
     </button>
 </form>
```

My directive:

```
<label for="{{txtid}}" ng-if="label" class="control-label col-xs-12" ng-class="{'col-sm-5': !isVertical}">{{label |translate}}</label>
<div ng-show="editMode" class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{'col-sm-7': !isGrouped && !isVertical, 'col-sm-offset-5': !label && !isGrouped && !isVertical}">
    <input tabindex="{{tabIndex}}" id="{{txtId}}" placeholder="{{placeholder |translate}}" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="displayValue" comma-dot-converter="" ng-blur="updateModel();execBlur();" ng-change="valueChange()" />
</div>
```

I use `ng-blur` to check some numeric formats...
But if I hit enter in the textbox my form is not submitted anymore and if I remove the `ng-blur` the form is submitted when enter key is pressed.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a plunker, maybe? Is ng-blur really the optimal place to check validity?

Comment: IMO, there are too many listeners here. try removing ng-change. ng-change is invoked on each key press. If you have ng-change then you don't require ng-blur. In general, ng-submit and ng-blur works together.